# Trying to divide 2 count in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, mysql-workbench

I've been stuck for the past 3 hours on a single query.
I have to divide the 2 counts below :

```
--Count the number of event hosted by each friend
SELECT friend_ID, COUNT(*) as TotalNumberOfEventHosted
FROM EVENT_
GROUP BY friend_id;

--Count the number of confirmed event
SELECT friend_ID, COUNT(*) as NbrOfConfirmedEvent
FROM EVENT_
NATURAL JOIN PROPOSED_DATE
WHERE IS_CONFIRMED = TRUE
GROUP BY FRIEND_ID ;
```

Here are the respective screenshot :

[image: number of event hosted by each friend]
[image: number of confirmed event per organizer]

However, I'm unable to make a division, because I'm getting the following error : Subquery returns more than 1 row.

**The goal at the end is to get the event acceptance rate (number of validated events out of the total) for each organizer**. So to divide theNbrOfConfirmedEvent by the TotalNumberOfEventHosted.

And I wasn't able to combine both query. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: check the possibility to use `COUNT(DISTINCT col)`, `SUM(IS_CONFIRMED = TRUE)`

Comment: Post sample data of both tables and expected results in text format and not images to clarify what you want.

Comment: Sorry @forpas
The goal is to get the event acceptance rate (number of validated events out of the total) for each organizer.

I've edited the thread

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you could try using a left join on the two subquery 

    select a.friend_ID, a.TotalNumberOfEventHosted/b.NbrOfConfirmedEvent
    from  ( 
    SELECT friend_ID, COUNT(*) as TotalNumberOfEventHosted
    FROM EVENT_
    GROUP BY friend_id) a 
    left join ( 
        SELECT friend_ID, COUNT(*) as NbrOfConfirmedEvent
        FROM EVENT_
        NATURAL JOIN PROPOSED_DATE
        WHERE IS_CONFIRMED = TRUE
        GROUP BY FRIEND_ID 
    ) b on a.friend_ID = b.friend_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting those 2 queries in CTEs, joining them together in your main query and doing the division there

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? have a table with three columns one with friend_ID, other with hosted events and a third with confirmed events? If that is You are trying to do just add a column with a CountIF() or SumIF() checking is the event is confirmed

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take a look. The goal at the end is to get the event acceptance rate (number of validated events out of the total) for each organizer (friend_ID)